# update table with temp table very slow

Tags: mysql

I have a piece code that update multiple data(over 10000 in the stage).
It use temp table, but it's very very slow.
In the .net core 2.2 with Dapper, process time is over 600 sec and I don't know why?

I tried to two different way tried to fix it,
like that :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_example_temp(
        id int,
        name int,
        created_time datetime,
        creator_source int,
        creator_sn int,
        is_del int,
        isUpdate int);

-- and insert over 100000 data in this temp table, and next:

-- 1st practice
update t_example as a  , t_example_tempas as  b
set a.id = b.id ,
    a.created_time =b.created_time ,
    a.creator_sn =b.creator_sn ,
    a.is_del = b.is_del 
WHERE  a.id= b.id and b.isUpdate = 1;

-- 2nd practice
update t_example as a  inner join  t_example_tempas as b on a.id = b.id
set a.id = b.id ,
    a.created_time =b.created_time ,
    a.creator_sn =b.creator_sn ,
    a.is_del = b.is_del 
WHERE  b.isUpdate = 1;
```

two different syntax are also slowly...
How can I make that faster?

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to help you. Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ and pay special attention to the section on query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys...
I just forgot to add index in my temp table...

```
update t_example as a  , t_example_tempas as  b
set a.id = b.id ,
    a.created_time =b.created_time ,
    a.creator_sn =b.creator_sn ,
    a.is_del = b.is_del 
    index am_key(id) --ADD THIS ONE
WHERE  a.id= b.id and b.isUpdate = 1;
```

Sorry just stupid question.

Comment: Please accept your own answer too so we know you don't need help anymore.